# gdb 'info types' not printing C structure

Tags: c, gdb

I wanted to use gdb's `info types` to understand how a structure looks.

Saw the following behavior:
If the struct is defined as :

```
typedef struct {
...
...
} XX;
```

the `info types` command displays the structure format.

But if it's not typedef-ed, `info types` just tells that it's a struct. 
Gives no details of it's members.

Is this the expected behavior? Am I overlooking something?
Anyway to make the structure visible via info types? (w/o changing code).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ptype`, see builtin help:

```
(gdb) help ptype 
Print definition of type TYPE.
Usage: ptype[/FLAGS] TYPE | EXPRESSION
Argument may be any type (for example a type name defined by typedef,
or "struct STRUCT-TAG" or "class CLASS-NAME" or "union UNION-TAG"
or "enum ENUM-TAG") or an expression.
The selected stack frame's lexical context is used to look up the name.
Contrary to "whatis", "ptype" always unrolls any typedefs.

Available FLAGS are:
  /r    print in "raw" form; do not substitute typedefs
  /m    do not print methods defined in a class
  /M    print methods defined in a class
  /t    do not print typedefs defined in a class
  /T    print typedefs defined in a class
(gdb)
```

Here is an example for `redisContext`:

```
(gdb) ptype redisContext
type = struct redisContext {
    int err;
    char errstr[128];
    int fd;
    int flags;
    char *obuf;
    redisReader *reader;
    enum redisConnectionType connection_type;
    struct timeval *timeout;
    struct {
        char *host;
        char *source_addr;
        int port;
    } tcp;
    struct {
        char *path;
    } unix_sock;
}
(gdb)
```

Comment: Thanks @ks1322. Just to note, is not 'ptype struct redisContext' required? Is this C++? Also, is 'info types' behaving as expected?

Comment: No, `ptype struct redisContext` is not required, you can use both. `redisContext` is a part of redis client C API. I did not see any structure definitions in `info types` output, I guess it is expected.